# UIAlertView button action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertview

I have an `UIAlertView` that shows with this code that asks you to rate the application in the appstore.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate on the Appstore!" 
                                                message:@"" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Later" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

But I cannot figure out how to add an action to the OK button that takes you to the app in the **AppStore**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

How about this?

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        NSLog(@"Launching the store");
        //replace appname with any specific name you want
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/appname"]];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please change the method name to clickedButtonAtIndex .... There might be a chance that people may copy the same method name mentioned above and where the method will never be called....

Comment: Just a point, in ViewController.h, add: <UIAlertViewDelegate> after @interface ViewController : UIViewController  so it looks like this: "@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>"

Comment: So where do i call this method?
Is it going  to be called on it's own, since we added UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> on the header file, or we need to do something like [self alertView...] somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

You want something like the following:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index 0");
        // Add the action here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Clicked button index other than 0");
        // Add another action here
    }
}
```

NSLog's appear in the console when you press a button and help out whenever you want to debug/test anything.

Then for the action that you want, you'd write something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url_to_app_store"]];
```

Comment: For a 2 button alert, instead of checking if the button index is `0`, you would want to check if the cancel button was pressed or not `if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])`.

Comment: I was just adding extra help for checking in the future if any other buttons were to be pressed, then he could easily see and proceed.

Comment: Please change the method name to clickedButtonAtIndex .... There might be a chance that people may copy the same method name mentioned above and where the method will never be called....

Answer (score 0):

in swift : use this block of code to show alert message.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is an alert message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action:UIAlertAction) in print("This is in alert block")
})

alert.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```